How to get all docs and their corresponding embeddings from a Chromadb collection
I'd like to get all docs and their corresponding embeddings from a collection for a pairwise cosine similarity calculation to identify very similar documents. Using the following function,
def get_docs_and_embeddings(collection):
    results = collection.get(include=["documents", "embeddings"])
    docs = results["documents"]
    embeddings = results["embeddings"]
    return docs, embeddings               

I find that embeddings are not in the same order as the documents.  I'm using an external tool to calculate pairwise similarity because I find it quicker than the built-in query.  What is the right way to approach this? Thanks a lot!

The documents and embeddings both have 'doc_id' attributes?

Yes. I think I know the reason now. Chromadb re-sorted the "doc_id".

The sort order is not guaranteed, but you can sort one of the partial results to match the other (or sort both by id).
